# Unable to Retrieve Movie Posters Using TMDB API in Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, retrofit2

I am currently developing an Android app using Android Studio, and I'm facing an issue with retrieving movie posters from the TMDB API. I have successfully fetched movie titles, but I am struggling to display the corresponding movie posters in my app.

Problem Description:

I am using the TMDB API to fetch a list of movies, including their titles and poster paths. While I can display the movie titles in my app, the movie posters are not showing up. I have verified that the API response contains valid poster paths, and I'm using the Glide library to load the images.

Code Details:

Here's a snippet from my `MovieAdapter` class:

kotlin
Copy code

```kotlin
class MovieAdapter(private val movieList: MutableList<Result>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder>() {

    inner class MovieViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val movieImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieImage)
        var moviename: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.movieName)

        fun bind(movie: Result) {
            val requestOptions = RequestOptions().transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(16))
            val posterUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500${movie.posterPath}"
            Glide.with(itemView.context)
                .load(posterUrl)
                .apply(requestOptions)
                .into(movieImage)
            moviename.text = movie.title
        }
    }

    // ... rest of the adapter code ...
}
```

Specific Issues:

The `movieAdapter.setMovies(movieList)` call is not displaying movie posters.
I have verified that the poster paths from the API response are correct.
The `Glide.with().load()` method is not loading the images.
What I have tried:

- Checked the API response for valid poster paths.
- Verified that the posterUrl formed is correct.
- Ensured the Glide library is properly implemented.

Request for Assistance:

I am seeking guidance on how to correctly display movie posters in my app using the TMDB API and the Glide library. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. If you need more specific code snippets or additional information, please let me know.